# How to put all my cart items in an XML Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Does anyone know why it's returning only 1 item?
There are 2 items in my cart. Here is the "item_dict" variable:

```
 cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=current_user)
 for cart_item in cart_items:
        total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
        quantity += cart_item.quantity

        item_dict = f"""
            <item>
                <id>{cart_item.product.id}</id>\r\n
                <description>{cart_item.product.name}</description>\r\n
                <quantity>{cart_item.quantity}</quantity>\r\n
                <amount>{cart_item.product.price}</amount>\r\n
            </item>
            """
        return HttpResponse(item_dict)
```

In my HttpResponse(item_dict) it is returning me only 1 item
[image]

Meu objetivo é poder devolver todos os itens do meu carrinho no meu XML
[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely reason is the `return` statement is inside the `for` loop, so the loop will always return on the first iteration.  You probably need something more like:

```
returnable_string = ''

for cart_item in cart_items:
    returnable_string += f"""
        <item>
            <id>{cart_item.product.id}</id>\r\n
            <description>{cart_item.product.name}</description>\r\n
            <quantity>{cart_item.quantity}</quantity>\r\n
            <amount>{cart_item.product.price}</amount>\r\n
        </item>
        """

return HttpResponse(returnable_string)
```

Although this example doesn't deal with adding up the `total` and `quantity`, notice that the `return` statement is outside the `for` loop.

Comment: it wasn't even a question of entering or leaving httpresponse, it gave the same result. But creating a variable outside and sending the data there worked! Thanks